# Perl: Run script on multiple files in multiple directories

Tags: perl, sh

I have a perl script that reads a .txt and a .bam file, and creates an output called output.txt.

I have a lot of files that are all in different folders, but are only slightly different in the filename and directory path.

All of my txt files are in different subfolders called PointMutation, with the full path being

```
/Volumes/Lab/Data/Darwin/Patient/[Plate 1/P1H10]/PointMutation
```

The text(s) in the bracket is the part that changes, But the Patient subfolder contains all of my txt files.

My .bam file is located in a subfolder named DNA with a full path of

```
/Volumes/Lab/Data/Darwin/Patient/[Plate 1/P1H10]/SequencingData/DNA
```

Currently how I run this script is go on the terminal

```
cd /Volumes/Lab/Data/Darwin/Patient/[Plate 1/P1H10]/PointMutation
perl ~/Desktop/Scripts/Perl.pl "/Volumes/Lab/Data/Darwin/Patient/[Plate 
1/P1H10]/PointMutation/txtfile.txt" "/Volumes/Lab/Data/Darwin/Patient/[Plate 
1/P1H10]/SequencingData/DNA/bamfile.bam"
```

With only 1 or two files, that is fairly easy, but I would like to automate it once the files get much larger. Also once I run these once, I don't want to do it again, but I will get more information from the same patient, is there a way to block a folder from being read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
for my $dir (glob "/Volumes/Lab/Data/Darwin/Patient/*/"){
    # skip if not a directory
    if (! -d $dir) {
        next;
    }
    my $txt = "$dir/PointMutation/txtfile.txt";
    my $bam = "$dir/SequencingData/DNA/bamfile.bam";

    # ... you magical stuff here
}
```

This is assuming that all directories under `/Volumes/Lab/Data/Darwin/Patient/` follow the convention.

That said, more long term/robust way of organizing analyses with lots of different files all over the place is either 1) organize all files necessary for each analysis under one directory, or 2) to create meta files (i'd use JSON/yaml) which contain the necessary file names.

Comment: Is there a way to set the current directory in the script to the PointMutation folder?I am fairly new to perl, what is JSON/yaml, and is a meta file a temporary file?

Comment: You can do `chdir "/whatever/directory/you/want". And yes, I think it's a good idea to change into the most relevant directory. JSON and YAML are common format for storing simple data structures, see their wikipedia pages, and the corresponding perl modules JSON and YAML. But, if you're just getting started, the sample I gave and the `chdir` function should get you far.

Comment: *"create meta files (i'd use JSON/yaml) which contain the necessary file names"* For just a list of file paths, there's no reason to use anything other than a flat file. And you can magically read it without involving an external module!

Comment: @Borodin How would you do it without JSON/yaml?